# Quick way to determine if a url is just pasted?

Tags: php

Is there a way in order to determine that a page is accessed by simply copy pasting the url or just typed it in the address bar?
Is it possible to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: While it's a valid question, please be careful how you use this. There's absolutely nothing specified in the HTTP protocol to allow you to detect this, and that's the only thing you have. Don't *rely* on this for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: There's one way you can be sure your website is not typed. Name it like this http://thelongestlistofthelongeststuffatthelongestdomainnameatlonglast.com/

Comment: Do you consider following "paste" or "Regular navigation": user clicks on a link in some application and as result default browser is opened? Clearly navigation for a user...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that's the only common indicator that your link was clicked (or not) from another page, that is probably your best bet depending on why you care (especially if traffic may be coming from external sites), but it's not 100% accurate.

Some browser add-ons, security settings, antivirus tools, proxy servers and firewalls will not pass this variable.

Also, search bots and other non-browser means of accessing your site will usually not pass in a HTTP_REFERER heading.

Most browsers will strip this if they linked to your page from a secure page (i.e. http link in an https page)

Finally, this is an easy property to fake. Browser add-ons and other tools (e.g. cUrl) allow you to set this to whatever you want.

Answer (score 5):

Using the referrer (or absence thereof) is not reliable, but is a strong indicator. Also look for cookies that may have been set on earlier pages of the site.

Comment: How can you say that using the referrer is not reliable? Can you give some examples?